# Highlight text in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

I have a  textarea and a div. I want that when I hover over a particular word in the div, it also highlights the word in the textarea exactly like this...

http://translate.google.com/#hi|en|%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%20%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE%20%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%AC%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%9C%E0%A4%BC%20%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%B9

Please help...

Comment: That's not a `textarea`. Case closed.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to highlight portions of text inside a `textarea`.

That being said, it is a common practice (and translate.google.com uses that) to show overlay above/below the element to highlight its parts...

Answer (score 3):

If you firebug he the Google Translate, you can see it's not a textarea. The GTranslate system wrapps the words with "`spans`" and dynamically change the background colour of the `span` `on hover`.

Answer (score 1):

that is not a text area. you can achieve this by wrapping text in span and styling it